$(z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}=4maz\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)\right)$
For any integer $m>1$ prove that
$$(z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}=4maz\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)\right)$$
My first thought is to try using induction on $m$. Therefore I first set $m=2$ then the right hand side is
$$8az\left(z^2+a^2\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)= 8az^3+8a^3z$$
and the left hand side is
\begin{align}
(z+a)^4-(z-a)^4&=[(z+a)^2+(z-a)^2][(z+a)^2+(z-a)^2]\\
&=(2z^2+2a^2)(4az)\\
&=8az^3+8a^3z
\end{align}
this proves the identity for the case $m=2$. Next, I want to expand the left hand side as
\begin{align}
(z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}&=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}{{2m}\choose k}z^{2m-k}a^k-\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k {{2m}\choose k}z^{2m-k}a^k\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}{{2m}\choose {2k+1}} z^{2m-(2k+1)}a^{2k+1}\\
&=4maz\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{2}{{2m}\choose {2k+1}} z^{2m-2k-2}a^{2k}
\end{align}
and for the induction assumption I will assume that
$$4maz\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{2}{{2m}\choose {2k+1}} z^{2m-2k-2}a^{2k}=4maz\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)\right)$$
that is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{2}{{2m}\choose {2k+1}} z^{2m-2k-2}a^{2k}=\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z^2+a^2\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)\right) \tag{1}$$
To proceed with the induction process I would have to show that the above assumption implies the identity for the case of $m+1$, but this seems extremely messy and, looking at expression 1 above I'm beginning to think that there must be a simpler method than induction, such as comparing the roots of both sides of equation 1. I would greatly appreciate any help here. Is my work so far correct? How would one proceed with induction here? Is there a simpler way?
EDIT: I see that this question has been asked before, and the accepted answer does show a simpler way to solve the problem without induction. However I would like to see if the induction approach can be salvaged.

This question is similar to: Prove that for any integer $m>1$, $(z+a)^{2m}-(z-a)^{2m}=4maz\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}[z^2+a^2\cot^2(k\pi/2m)]$.. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That answer doesn't address how to complete the induction step

I don't believe induction is going to be helpful for this problem.
